# which database technology to use for many user searchable columns

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cassandra, data-modeling

We currently have a system where the user can slice their data on a large (20+) number of dimensions to narrow down exactly what they want to see. Currently MySQL is choking on the effort mainly because we don't have enough indexes to handle all the used combinations. The users have a date-based field that is included with each query but the rest of the fields are combined in a random manner across the userbase. Is there a database product that is more optimised for this type of search?

I've been looking at products such as MongoDB or Cassandra to reorganize the data but I'm not sure they'll be able to handle the search requirement efficiently. Looking for guidance.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the search requirements? What sort of filtering are you doing by dimensions (equality, ranges, full text, ..?). Given 20+ dimensions it sounds like you should really be considering a search engine product (for example, something based on Apache Lucene like ElasticSearch or Solr). A search engine solution will have more advanced functionality like facets & proximity search to help users drill into data across that many dimensions. If your requirements are more modest, you could possibly bend another data store (even MySQL) to suit by adjusting your data model.

Comment: Almost all properties are in dropdowns with one keyword search component. The document count will be north of 50 mil soon. The tricky part is the data is hierarchical meaning we have parent nodes that contain child nodes that contain child nodes. We need to efficiently query the parent nodes to receive documents nested under the children.